# Can I change the path to Drush?

Tags: drush

I am trying to use omega-wizard but I think I am using the wrong version of Drush. I want to use the drush the is in Acquia Dev Desktop but when i type `which drush` I get the one that was last installed with MAMP (running OSX).

When trying to run `drush omega-wizard` I get this message:

```
The drush command 'omega-wizard' could not be found.  Run `drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you   [error]
have installed new extensions.
                                                                                                                            [error]
Drush was not able to start (bootstrap) the Drupal database.
Hint: This may occur when Drush is trying to:
 * bootstrap a site that has not been installed or does not have a configured database. In this case you can select another
site with a working database setup by specifying the URI to use with the --uri parameter on the command line. See `drush
topic docs-aliases` for details.
 * connect the database through a socket. The socket file may be wrong or the php-cli may have no access to it in a jailed
shell. See http://drupal.org/node/1428638 for details.

Drush was attempting to connect to: 
 Drupal version         :  7.34                                                         
 Site URI               :  `http://default`                                               
 Default theme          :  garland                                                      
 Administration theme   :  garland                                                      
 PHP executable         :  /Applications/Dev Desktop/php5_5/bin/php                     
 PHP configuration      :  "/Applications/Dev Desktop/php5_5/bin/php.ini"               
 PHP OS                 :  Darwin                                                       
 Drush version          :  6.2.0                                                        
 Drush configuration    :                                                               
 Drush alias files      :                                                               
 Drupal root            :  /Users/khrysztov/Sites/devdesktop/acquia-drupal-7.34.40.6204 
 Site path              :  sites/default                                                
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files
```

I cannot see any reference to the database there in the parameters and the default theme is not Garland.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just edit your `.bashrc` file and add an alias for drush: `alias drush='php ~/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php'` (edit to meet your environment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Paul worked (thanks):

alias drush='"/Applications/Dev Desktop/drush/drush"'

Needed inner double quotes to allow for space in Dev Desktop.

Comment: Or just use `alias drush='/Applications/Dev\ Desktop/drush/drush'`.

Comment: Yeah for some reason the escape character wasn't working. I was just pleased to get it working after spending a long time looking for a solution so I was happy with the double quotes.